# Antergos MariaDB problems

Tags: arch-linux, mysql, mariadb, antergos

I've just installed the mariadb package and doesn't work (doesn't start), I've these outputs:

> systemctl status -l mariadb.service

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

> journalctl | grep mariadb | tail

```
 action org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units for system-bus-name::1.110 [systemctl start mariadb.service] (owned by unix-user:velzm)
 dic 04 08:17:21 nmveliz systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 dic 04 08:17:21 nmveliz systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
 dic 04 08:17:21 nmveliz systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

> systemctl status mariadb.service

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; ven
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-12-03 16:44:12 CST; 
  Process: 1959 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUST
  Process: 1906 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ]
  Process: 1903 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSRE
  Main PID: 1959 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

dic 03 16:44:12 nmveliz mysqld[1959]: 2016-12-03 16:44:12 1396413908  
dic 03 16:44:12 nmveliz mysqld[1959]: 2016-12-03 16:44:12 1396419816  
dic 03 16:44:12 nmveliz mysqld[1959]: 2016-12-03 16:44:12 1396419816  
dic 03 16:44:12 nmveliz mysqld[1959]: 2016-12-03 16:44:12 1396419816  
dic 03 16:44:12 nmveliz mysqld[1959]: 2016-12-03 16:44:12 1396419816  
dic 03 16:44:12 nmveliz mysqld[1959]: 2016-12-03 16:44:12 1396419816  
dic 03 16:44:12 nmveliz systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process ex  
dic 03 16:44:12 nmveliz systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database  
dic 03 16:44:12 nmveliz systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered fa  
dic 03 16:44:12 nmveliz systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with res  
lines 1-18/18 (END)
```

> journalctl -xe

```
dic 03 16:56:30 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:30 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:30 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:30 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:30 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:30 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:31 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:31 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:32 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:32 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:32 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:32 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:32 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:32 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:32 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:32 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:32 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:32 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:32 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:32 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:32 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:32 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:32 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:32 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:32 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:32 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:32 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:32 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:32 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:32 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:32 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:32 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:32 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:32 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:33 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:33 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:33 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:33 1401670818
dic 03 16:56:33 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:33 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:33 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:33 1401676737
dic 03 16:56:33 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:33 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:33 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:33 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:33 nmveliz mysqld[2707]: 2016-12-03 16:56:33 1401676738
dic 03 16:56:33 nmveliz systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process ex
dic 03 16:56:33 nmveliz systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
dic 03 16:56:33 nmveliz systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered fa
dic 03 16:56:33 nmveliz systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with res
dic 03 16:56:33 nmveliz sudo[2649]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session
```

Comment: use `status -l` to get the full width output, and `journalctl|tail` similarly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Antergos install.

It seams mariadb  doesn't install properly and cant access its directories

I fixed my problem doing...

```
sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/ --ldata=/var/lib/mysql/
```

[unable to launch mysqld in arch linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216829/unable-to-launch-mysqld-in-arch-linux)

But there is another solution, changing the ownership of /var/lib/mysql to mysql user and group

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813552/linux-antergos-install-mysql